# 'Missing initializer in const declaration.' error in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a problem with a react class, its says that I have a missing initializer in const declaration. I don't know how to fix it after googling.

Here is my class

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const axios = require('axios').default;
import { HttpClient } from "./services/httpClient";


export const Popup: React.FC<any> = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState(null);
  const handleStatusInput = (e) => setText(e);
  const httpClient = new HttpClient();
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    prepareFileForSending();
  }, []);

  function prepareFileForSending() {


    // http request to send an email with the prepared document to sign
    httpClient.test("matej").then((responseData) => {
      if (responseData !== "") {
        setText(responseData);
      } else {
        handleStatusInput(false);
      }
      setLoaded(true);
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
     
      {text && (
        <div >
          <span>{text}</span>
        </div>
      )}
     
    </div>
  );
};

export default Popup;
```

Here is the error:
`ERROR in ./src/popup.tsx Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): SyntaxError: C:\SourceCodes\Chrome\src\popup.tsx: Missing initializer in const declaration. (31:18)`

[image]

Here is the problem:

[image]

Here is webpack.config.js, i don't think it is a problem with webpack, but I post it just in case
Random text just to cover criteira of people trying to post about my ababababa

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
 entry: {
   popup: './src/popup.tsx'
 },
  output: {
   filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
            }
        }
    }]
  },
  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/popup.html",
      filename: "popup.html"
  }),
  new CopyPlugin({
    patterns: [
      { from: "public"},
    ],
  }),
],
};
```

Comment: You need to add the @babel/preset-typescript as I said here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71736126/5689074

Answer (score 2):

You need to change

```js
 const axios = require('axios').default;
```

for this

```js
import axios from 'axios';
```

and add

```js
import React from 'react';
```

and

```js
options: {
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react','@babel/preset-typescript']
}
```

Comment: Nope, still the same

Comment: and import react?

Comment: I have that aswell, just pasted badly, now it is changed

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Comment: If yes, do you have the "@babel/typescript" installed and set as a presets on the babel config?

Comment: I just posted the webpack, and yes, I have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243579/discussion-between-mgm793-and-wet-pantz).

Comment: this  actually resolved "This experimental syntax requires enabling one of the following parser plugin(s): "flow", "typescript".

Answer (score 0):

```
export const Popup = (): React.FC<any> => {
```

`Popup` is a function in general, so let it be typed as function.

**UPD**

```
export const Popup: React.FC = (): JSX.Element => {
```

Where `React.FC` is component type, and `JSX.Element` - what the component returns.

Comment: Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'FC<{}>'.
  Type 'ReactElement<any, any>' provides no match for the signature '(props: { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any>'.ts(2322)

Comment: My bad.  Sure it must be `export const Popup: React.FC = (): JSX.Element => {`